# How to use switchMap in RxJs Subsciption array?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I want to use `switchMap` in my subscriptions array, I want to call `invokeRequest` method which triggers http requests, basically I want to cancel subscription if same http call is triggered, can anyone please help.

```
private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
this.subscriptions.push(trigger.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe((e) =>
 this.invokeRequest(callConfig, e))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switchMap` in the pipe like below:

```
private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

this.subscriptions.push(
  trigger.pipe(
    skip(1),
    switchMap((e) => this.invokeRequest(callConfig, e))
  ).subscribe(resp => {
    // do something with the `invokeRequest` response
  })
);
```

This brings two main benefits:

1. As you pointed out, when `trigger` emits a new value, the previous `invokeRequest` is cancelled (if it's still pending) and a new one is started.
2. When you `unsubscribe()` your subscriptions (e.g when the component is destroyed), if there is some request pending, it's cancelled too. The way it was before (being called within the `trigger.subscribe()` callback) it would not cancel the request.

Comment: Agreed! I'd also mark the better practice for `Subscription`: `private subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();` and then just use `this.subscriptions.add(...` in the same way. It allows you only one time unsubscribe for all of your subscriptions in OnDestroy hook.